# Why this question appeared among interesting questions?

Tags: support

Few moments ago I have checked recent interesting question list and this one appeared today between hot questions on top of my SO questions screen filtered by favourite tags.

[Clickonce WPF application publish no option to specify deployment url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24123637/clickonce-wpf-application-publish-no-option-to-specify-deployment-url)

But I see latest comment added in August and the question had last substantial activity in 2014. Why this happened, is it a bug?

---

It seems there was some pending edit (it wrote - modified by ..., but no such edit is visible, perhaps the edit was later refused?)

[image]

Comment: Someone posted an answer and then deleted it ~1hr ago

Comment: Shouldn't the `modifed xx mins ago` status be removed (reset back) too?

Comment: If you think along the lines of the state of the question was "modified" by having an answer added then that state was "modified" by having it removed - it kind of makes sense...

Comment: Yes, but It would be nice to have an option to remove old questions from the `interesting` tab.